# Visual Studio Mac open open F# solution as file

Tags: f#, visual-studio-mac

After I update VS-Mac to 7.3 my F# Solution is opened as a plain text file (it is not loaded).

I create a empty solution and it load.

I could build the solution with MSBUILD from the command line.

```
Visual Studio Community 2017 for Mac
Version 7.3 (build 797)
Runtime:
    Mono 5.4.1.7 (2017-06/e66d9abbb27) (64-bit)
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)

    Package version: 504010007

NuGet
Versión: 4.3.1.4445

.NET Core
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Versión de tiempo de ejecución: 2.0.0
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/2.0.0/Sdks
Versión del SDK: 2.0.0
SDK de MSBuild: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.4.1/lib/mono/msbuild/15.0/bin/Sdks

Xamarin.Profiler
Versión: 1.6.0
Ubicación: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Xamarin.Android
Versión: 8.1.0.24 (Visual Studio Community)
Android SDK: /Users/mamcx/Library/Developer/Xamarin/android-sdk-macosx
    Versiones de Android admitidas:
        7.1 (nivel de API 25)

Versión de las herramientas del SDK: 25.2.5
Versión de las herramientas de plataforma del SDK: 25.0.5
Versión de las herramientas de compilación del SDK: 25.0.3

Java SDK: /usr
java version "1.8.0_131"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_131-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.131-b11, mixed mode)

El código EPL de Android Designer está disponible EPL:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 9.1 (13532)
Build 9B55

Xamarin.Mac
Version: 4.0.0.214 (Visual Studio Community)

Xamarin Inspector
Version: 1.3.2
Hash: 461f09a
Branch: 1.3-release
Build date: Tue, 03 Oct 2017 18:26:57 GMT
Client compatibility: 1

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 11.4.0.214 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: c4240f3f
Branch: d15-5
Build date: 2017-11-08 17:28:18-0500

Build Information
Release ID: 703000797
Git revision: ff055b3ecaaeb4229434d0ca871c7d67c62f6388
Build date: 2017-11-30 14:34:51-05
Xamarin addins: 351fc12d4f2367490f8fc2a66b14690d825bb7f1
Build lane: monodevelop-lion-d15-5

Operating System
Mac OS X 10.12.6
Darwin 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0
    Wed Oct  4 00:17:00 PDT 2017
    root:xnu-3789.71.6~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64

Enabled user installed addins
Internet of Things (IoT) development (Preview) 7.1
```

BTW: When try to load the update for "Visual Studio Updater 1.7" it download and when try to apply I get error "No updates Found".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the problem:

I click on "Convert solution format" I it change:

```
-Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 12.00
+Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File, Format Version 15.00
 # Visual Studio 2012
```

When revert back to Version 12.00 it open again fine.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your F# Language Binding extension is **Enabled**

[image]

Comment: @mamcx Check the IDE logs for errors (Help menu / Open Log Directory)

Comment: @mamcx Can you create a new F#-based project (in a new solution)?

Comment: Yes I can. And it open